# get linkedin profile with field selectors

Tags: java, linkedin-api, spring-social

Hi I am using linkedin api to get user's profile and being able to get user's statndard profile as returned by https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~ but I want to add field selectors as http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name) but it throws

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~
at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:850)
```

I googled it and some says it is because of proxy and may be you are not able to reach `api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~` but i have no proxy set.

I guess it is because of `':'` for field selectors. I have tried different approaches but didn't succeed. Even spring-social-linkedin throws same exception when try to `linkedInTemplate.profileOperations().getUserProfileFull()`

EDIT : I am able to get full profile using PHP and DotNet code but not working in java.

Help me.

Comment: The URL looks ok. You're using http*s* for the first, http for the second appearance in the question.

Comment: I have tried both ways it doesn't change exception. :(

Comment: Too bad. I have used LinkedIn API with Java (using [Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)). Here's the exact profile that I used at that time: `"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,picture-url,headline,industry,site-standard-profile-request:(url))"`.

Comment: yes scribe is working for me too...they have done nothing extra then my code. just cant figure out what is going wrong here.. I dont want to dependency

Answer (score 1):

This exception is caused due to proxy. Add the following code to your source:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxy");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```